# why this assembly .com file print 2 non-stop?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

this is the assembly code written in .com file for 16 bit machine:
it is a code for gcd calculation, have 2 functions: calc_gcd calling to clac_mod.
calc_mod works fine and i assume calc_gcd as well, but the printing in calc_gcd prints the digit 2 (the correct answer BTW) infinity number of times to the screen.
why is that?

```
        org 100h
        mov ax,0006
        mov bx,0002

        call calc_gcd
        mov ah,4Ch
        int 21h 
        msg dw ' ','$'

        calc_mod:   
           start_mod:
           cmp ax, bx
           jbe end_mod
           sub ax,bx
           jmp start_mod
    end_mod: 
        ret

        calc_gcd:

       cmp bx,0000h
       je end_gcd
       call calc_mod
       xor ax, bx
       xor bx, ax
       xor ax, bx
       add ax, '0'
       mov [msg], ax
       mov dx,msg
       mov ah,9
       int 21h  

      call calc_gcd
        end_gcd: 
         ret
```

Comment: You really need to use a debugger to see how the register values are getting messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few logic mistakes in your code:

```
mov ax,0006        ;ax = 6
mov bx,0002        ;bx = 2
[...]
calc_mod:          ;you don't need 2 labels, choose 1
start_mod:
cmp ax, bx         ;6 = 2?
jbe end_mod        ;exit call
sub ax,bx          ;ax = 6-2 = 4
jmp start_mod      ;loop until ax=bx=2
```

So in this code you declare 2 variables x=6 and y=2

Then you substract x-y until x <= y

So at this point, with the numbers you used, **AX=2 and BX=2**

```
calc_gcd:
    cmp bx,0000h         ;BX=2 and is never touched in the code
    je end_gcd           ;jmp never taken
    call calc_mod
    xor ax, bx           ;AX = 2 xor 2 = 0
    xor bx, ax           ;BX = 2 xor 0 = 2
    xor ax, bx           ;AX = 0 xor 2 = 2
    add ax, '0'          ;AX = 32h
    mov [msg], ax
    mov dx,msg           ;msg = '2'
    [...]
    call calc_gcd        ;do this again and again
end_gcd:
    ret
```

Searching 'gcd assembly' on google gives you a lot of code examples to calculate the gcd.

Start from there.